# Como capturar el evento del boton izquierdo del mouse cuando se suelta con c#?

Tags: c#

Hola e buscado por todos lados y no logro dar con la solucion, lo que quiero hacer es, detectar y capturar el evento del click izquierdo del mouse de cuando el boton se suelta (MouseUp), quiero solamente de esa boton, independientemente sobre cualquier ventana de windows, ya sea administrada o no administrada, y que sea mediante el llamado a alguna api de windows, por favor en lo posible no enviarme ningun enlace, porque e buscado en la mayoria de los enlaces y no doy con la solucion, por favor le agradeceria mucho si me podria facilitar un ejemplo de codigo sencillo y funcional de como hacer lo que busco, desde ya muchas gracias.

//Esto es un ejemplo de la estructura que pretendo, desconosco que libreria y constantes debo
//usar.

// Importacion de la libreria y constante.

// -----------------------------

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)

{

base.WndProc(ref m);

if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY) //Detectamos el evento

{

// ...........

}

}
```

// -----------------------------

Comment: Agrega el codigo que haz intentado y que dudas tienes.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si no queres un enlace, entonces por favor agrega todo lo que investigaste, probaste, porque nadie sabe que fue lo que miraste, y capaz te ofrecen algo que ya miraste...

Comment: Hola ahi agregue un codigo, repito el codigo es solo un ejemplo de estructura, nose cual es la libreria y constante que hace referencia al evento de cuando se suelta el click izquierdo.

Comment: Hay un motivo de cierre que es por pedir librerias :(... entiendo lo que queres hacer.... no tengo ni idea como se hace... sobre todo para leer la cola de eventos general de windows...

Comment: Perdon, pasa que mire casi todos los enlaces de stackoverflow referido a mi pregunta, y todos hacen ferencia al evento de cuando se apreta el click izquierdo del mouse y no cuando de suelta el click, era mas que nada por eso mi pedido.

Comment: No entendi lo que dijiste de (Hay un motivo de cierre que es por pedir librerias), cuando me refiero a libreria, me refiero a libreria de windows.